# Python compare string in file against multiple files in a directory

Tags: python, file

I've got the below code to work partially but ultimately I want the first file(input.txt) to be checked against mutliple files in a directory and output a string and the file name(from the directory) if it is found. Any suggestions ?

```
 f = open('out.txt', 'w')
   filenames = ["input.txt", "compare.dat", "compare2.dat", "compare3.dat"]
   files = [open(name) for name in filenames]
   sets = [set(line.strip() for line in file) 
           for file in files]
   common = set.union(*sets)
   my_list = list(common)
   my_list.sort()
   print (my_list)
   for file in files: file.close()


   for line in my_list:
      if.write(line+'\n')
   if.close()
```

Comment: You want contents of 1st file to be matched with every other file or a particular string in 1st file to be matched with every other file?

Comment: Ideally the first file strings that are not !* (commented out) against multiple files

Comment: Anyone? ? ? ? ?

Comment: have you checked the solution I posted?

Answer (score 0):

This solution could work:

```
def readB(x):
for name in filesnames:
    with open(name) as resultFile:
        for line in resultFile:
            if x in line:
               print x,name


def readA():
 with open('A.txt') as bondNumberFile: ## instead of A.txt call the .txt file from which every other file has to be matched
    for line in bondNumberFile:
        readB(line.rstrip())

readA()
```

Comment: Thanks , doesn't appear to be working for me. Perhaps I have done something wrong. The two functions should be used in conjunction with my script ?

Comment: Nope, my code is independent. Just how you are getting `filenames` is related to your code!!

Comment: So, did it worked?. IF yes, do upvote and accept for future users!!